# Паттерн декоратор

Tags: java

```
    package homework3.calcs.additional;
    
    import homework3.calcs.api.ICalculator;
    
    
    public class CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator implements ICalculator {
    
        ICalculator calculator;
    
        public CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator(ICalculator c) {
            calculator = c;
        }
        public long getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    
        public ICalculator getCalculator() {
            return calculator;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public double divide(double a, double b) {
            return calculator.divide(a,b);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double multiplication(double a, double b) {
            return calculator.multiplication(a,b);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double plus(double a, double b) {
            return calculator.plus(a,b);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double minus(double a, double b) {
            return calculator.minus(a,b);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double square(double a, int b) {
            return calculator.square(a,b);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double module(double a) {
            return calculator.module(a);
        }
    
        @Override
        public double root(double a) {
            return calculator.root(a);
        }
    }
Второй класс 

package homework3.calcs.additional;

import homework3.calcs.api.ICalculator;

public class CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator implements ICalculator {

    private ICalculator calculator;
    private double memory;
    private double mod;
    public CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(ICalculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }

    @Override
    public double divide(double a, double b) {
        mod = calculator.divide(a,b);
        return calculator.divide(a,b);
    }

    @Override
    public double multiplication(double a, double b) {
        mod = calculator.multiplication(a,b);
        return calculator.multiplication(a,b);
    }

    @Override
    public double plus(double a, double b) {
        mod = calculator.plus(a,b);
        return calculator.plus(a,b);
    }

    @Override
    public double minus(double a, double b) {
        mod = calculator.minus(a,b);
        return calculator.minus(a,b);
    }

    @Override
    public double square(double a, int b) {
        mod = calculator.square(a,b);
        return calculator.square(a,b);
    }

    @Override
    public double module(double a) {
        mod = calculator.module(a);
        return calculator.module(a);
    }
    @Override
    public double root(double a) {
        mod = calculator.root(a);
        return calculator.root(a);
    }
    public void setMemory() {
        memory = 0;
        if (memory == 0) {
            memory = mod;
        }

    }
    public double getMemory() {
        return memory;
    }
    public ICalculator getCalculator() {
        return calculator;
    }
}
Интерфейс 

package homework3.calcs.api;

public interface ICalculator {
     double divide(double a, double b);

     double multiplication(double a, double b) ;

     double plus(double a, double b) ;

     double minus(double a, double b) ;

     double square(double a, int b) ;

     double module(double a) ;

     double root(double a) ;
}

Main

package homework3.runners;

import homework3.calcs.additional.CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator;
import homework3.calcs.additional.CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator;
import homework3.calcs.api.ICalculator;
import homework3.calcs.simple.CalculatorWithMathExtends;

public class CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecoratorMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICalculator ic = new CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator(new CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(new CalculatorWithMathExtends()));
        double sum = ic.plus(4.1,ic.plus(ic.multiplication(15,7),ic.square(ic.divide(28,5),2)));
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Математические методы работают, но два новые метода getCount и getMemory через ссылку ic без каста не могу вызвать, а если с кастом, то getCount работает, а getMemory вызывает ошибку ClassCastException. Короче нужна помощь, как можно без каста сделать и без создания объектов типа отличного от ic

Comment: И вообще могу ли я каким-нибудь образом обратиться через ic к CalculatorWithMemoryDecarator в main? Имею ввиду к методам.

Comment: какое у тебя задание, что надо сделать? может оно в три строчки решается, а у тебя простыня из непонятного кода и ты сам понапридумывал себе сложностей.

Comment: Создать класс CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator и CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator
 11.1 Отличие от предыдущих CalculatorWithCounterAutoAgregationInterface и CalculatorWithMemory в том что данные классы реализуют интерфейс ICalculator.
 Добавить в эти классы метод ICalculator getCalculator() который будут возвращать вложенный в них калькулятор.

Comment: 11.5 Создать класс CalculatorDecoratorMain в котором будет точка входа (main метод). Cоздать переменную типа ICalculator записав в неё новый экземпляр класса CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator которому в конструктор был передан новый экземпляр класса CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator которому в конструтор был передан новый экземпляр класса CalculatorWithMathExtends. Используя созданную переменную посчитать выражения из задания 1. 
 11.6 Вывести в консоль результат. Вывести количество использований калькулятора. Вывести последнее сохранённое значение в памяти. Поможет выполнить instanceof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы требуете/ожидаете от данного шаблона того, что не может быть предоставлено.

Шаблон "декоратор" предназначен для динамической модификации *поведения*, т.е. методов входного объекта типа `ICalculator`.  Однако, к примеру в `CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator` никакой существенной модификации арифметических методов не происходит, а просто делегируются вызовы к "декорируемому" объекту.  Аналогично, "декорация" в `CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator` реализована не лучшим образом из-за того, что методы поля-калькулятора вызываются дважды, поэтому имело смысл переписать их хотя бы так:

```java
@Override
public double divide(double a, double b) {
    mod = calculator.divide(a,b);
    return mod;
}
```

Код, реализующий связь между полями `memory` и `mod`, тоже лишён практического смысла, скорей всего достаточно было иметь такие методы:

```java
public void clearMemory() {
    memory = 0;
}

public void setMemory() {
    memory = mod;
}

public double getMemory() {
    return memory;
}
```

> *как можно без каста сделать и без создания объектов типа отличного от `ic`*

Это взаимоисключающие требования.  Если требуется получить доступ к расширенным методам, реализованным в конкретном декораторе, то следует создавать ссылку на объект такого декоратора, как к примеру выполняется при работе с файлами, когда нужно читать файл построчно, используя метод `BufferedReader::readLine`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();
```

Аналогично и здесь, если нужен доступ к методам для доступа к "памяти", создаётся объект `CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator`, у которого можно вызывать как стандартные методы калькулятора, так и специфические методы декоратора:

```
CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator mc = new CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(
    new CalculatorWithMathExtends()
);
double res = mc.sum(1d, 2d);
mc.setMemory();
res = mc.divide(100d, 2.5);
System.out.println(mc.getMemory()); // -> 3.0
```

Также, если требуется доступ к специфическим методам декоратора А из декоратора В, нужно либо создавать класс с полем типа декоратор А:

```
interface ICommon {
    void commonBaz();
}

class DecoratorA implements ICommon {
    private ICommon common;
// constructor/getters/setters

    public void foo() {}
    public void bar() {}

    @Override
    public void commonBaz() {
        foo();
        common.commonBaz();
    }
}

class DecoratorBforA implements ICommon {
    private DecoratorA decA;
// constructor/getters/setters

    @Override
    public void commonBaz() {
        decA.bar();
        decA.commonBaz();
    }

    public DecoratorA getCommon() {
        return decA;
    }
}

DecoratorBforA b = new DecoratorBforA(new DecoratorA(new CommonImpl()));
b.getCommon().foo();
```

либо явно приводить к требуемому типу.

Comment: Явно привести к типу _CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator_ получается, но почему не могу явно привести к типу _CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator_, как я понимаю, потому, что у меня  _ICalculator ic = new CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator(new CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(new CalculatorWithMathExtends()))_. И если я правильно понимаю, то без создания второй переменной, я не могу вызвать методы _CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator_ ?

Comment: Да, их нужно создавать отдельно по очереди: `CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator memc = new CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(new CalculatorWithMathExtends()); CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator countc = new CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator(memc);`

Answer (score 0):

```
package homeWork3.runners;

import homeWork3.calcs.additional.CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator;
import homeWork3.calcs.additional.CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator;
import homeWork3.calcs.api.ICalculator;
import homeWork3.calcs.simple.CalculatorWithMathExtends;

public class CalculatorDecoratorMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICalculator ic = new CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator(new CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator(new CalculatorWithMathExtends()));
        double sum = ic.plus(ic.multiplication(15, 7), ic.plus(4.1, ic.square(ic.divide(28, 5), 2)));
        System.out.println("Выводим результат - " + sum);
        System.out.println("Выводим количество операций - " + ((CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator) ic).getCounter());
        System.out.println(((CalculatorWithMemoryDecorator) ((CalculatorWithCounterAutoDecorator)ic).getCalculator()).getMemory());
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]